# Selecting unique rows in R

Tags: r

There is a data.frame with duplicate values for the variable "Time"

```
> data.old
             Time  Count  Direction
1    100000630955     95          1
2    100000637570      5          0
3    100001330144      7          1
4    100001330144     33          1
5    100001331413     39          0
6    100001331413     43          0
7    100001334038      1          1
8    100001357594     50          0
```

You must leave all values without duplicates. And sum the values of the variable "Count" with duplicate values, i.e.

```
> data.new
             Time  Count  Direction
1    100000630955     95          1
2    100000637570      5          0
3    100001330144     40          1
4    100001331413     82          0
5    100001334038      1          1
6    100001357594     50          1
```

All I could find these unique values with the help of the command

```
> data.old$Time[!duplicated(data.old$Time)]
   [1] 100000630955 100000637570 100001330144 100001331413 100001334038 100001357594
```

I can do this in a loop, but maybe there is a more elegant solution

Comment: Try `aggregate(Count~Time, data.old, sum)`

Comment: In data.table: `setDT(data.old)[, .(Count=sum(Count), Direction=max(Direction)), by=Time]`.

Comment: @akrun Yes. Your decision is also suitable. But how to save other variables?

Comment: You can use `aggregate(Count ~., data.old, sum)` if all the other variables are grouping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach using `dplyr`. Is this what you want to do?

```
library(tidyverse)
data.old %>%
group_by(Time) %>%
   summarise(Count = sum(Count))
```

## Edit: Keeping other variables

OP has indicated a desire to keep the values of other variables in the dataframe, which `summarise` deletes. Assuming that all values of those other variables are the same for all the rows being summarised, you could use the `Mode` function from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode).

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Then change my answer to the following, with one call to Mode for each variable you want kept. This works with both numeric and character data.

```
library(tidyverse)
data.old %>%
group_by(Time) %>%
   summarise(Count = sum(Count), Direction = Mode(Direction))
```

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. But unfortunately, I forgot to indicate that the table has other variables. With this script, these variables disappear. I'll fix it now. How to save them?

Comment: @Dmitry I just edited my answer to accommodate additional variables.

Comment: Your answer helped to solve other problems. You really helped!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!

Answer (score 2):

here is the one by using aggregating function

```
data.new<-aggregate( Count~Time , data=data.old, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 library(dplyr)  
  data.old %>% group_by(Time) %>% summarise(Count = sum(Count), 
                                       Direction =  unique(Direction))
```

Of course, assuming you want to keep unique values of Direction column